# fourier transformation of f(t)

Tags: fourier-transform

I stucking on this exercise.

[image]

Should I use any Fourier Transformation rules?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer ^^

Comment: Du kannst z.b. die Lineäritetseigenschaften und Faltungsteorem brauchen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
f(t)&=(3e^{-2t^2}-5)\mathbf{1}_{(0,4)}(t) + 3e^{-2t^2}\mathbf{1}_{(0,4)^c}(t)\\
&= 3e^{-2t^2} - 5\mathbf{1}_{(0,5)}(t)
\end{aligned}

Then,
$\big(\mathcal{F}f\big)(s)=3\mathcal{F}(e^{-2t^2})(s)- 5\int^4_0e^{-2\pi st}\,dt$
The term on the right-hand side should be easily derived from the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function; the second is a direct computation.